# How draw such picture which indicate the motion direction?

Tags: image-processing, code-request

[image]

the direction picture is

[image]

In version 11.0.1,I notice a new function `ImageDisplacements` perhaps can do this,but maybe I miss something:

```
pics = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW75w.gif"];
Show[First[pics], 
 ListStreamPlot[#, 
    DataRange -> (PadLeft[#, 2] & /@ 
       List /@ ImageDimensions[First[pics]]), VectorStyle -> Red] & /@
   ImageDisplacements[pics]]
```

[image]

Poor effect..

#### Updata for material

The `gif` just have three frame,so I upload a `gif` maybe is more suitable of this task:
[image]

You also can get is by this code:

```
Export["test.gif", 
 ExampleData /@ 
  ExampleData[{"TestAnimation", "ToyVehicles"}, "Frames"], 
 "DisplayDurations" -> .5]
```

Comment: I threw on [tag:code-request] because I feel that this calls for nontrivial development.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for edit. :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `ListStreamPlot` expects the data array in a different order than it is arranged in an `Image`. You have to `Transpose@*Reverse` it:

```
flow = ImageDisplacements[pics];
ListStreamPlot[Transpose@Reverse@flow[[1]], 
 StreamPoints -> Fine, StreamColorFunction -> "CMYKColors"]
```

[image]

`flow[[1]]` is the flow from the first frame to the second frame. Replace it with `flow[[2]]` to visualize the flow from the second to the third.

Comment: How was `flow` defined?

Comment: @J.M.: Whoops, fixed.

Comment: So this is just a first frame to second frame?

Comment: @yode: "`flow[[1]]` is the flow from the first frame to the second frame. Replace it with `flow[[2]]` to visualize the flow from the second to the third."

Comment: @Rahul But the general trend is expected. :)

Comment: @yode: Then call `ImageDisplacements` with a list containing only the first and last frame.